# Why use .htaccess in every directory?

Tags: .htaccess, netbeans

In looking through the TodoList example that comes with NetBeans I noticed that they have the same `.htaccess` file in every single directory. Why would one want to do this approach rather than placing everything in a directory with a single `.htaccess` that covers all contained subdirectories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the approach. If you have one site that's monolithic, as in everything is more or less in one place, then having a single htaccess file in your document root is probably the best approach. When your site is modular or where each directory is sort of its own "webapp", having htaccess files in each of these directories means you can move them around, put them in other folders, or organize them however you want and not have to worry about changing things in a single htaccess file in the document root. This makes it more portable, but you'd only really care about that if your site is designed that way.

Comment: Are you familiar with that particular example? If so, any thoughts on the reason behind the choice they made.

Comment: @martin's Sorry, I'm not familiar with Netbeans' web deployment scheme. But the concept is that you can move each folder (or deployment) around to whatever directory you want without having to worry about constantly changing the main htaccess file. It may be something Netbeans does by default since it seems there really isn't much in these htaccess files that Netbeans generates.